# Get custom metadata for blob files in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have few 100 files in a folder in Blob Storage. Each of the files have custom metadata (Dictionary type). So when traversing through all files I need to get those metadata of each files.

So how to read that details. I tried using **GetMetadata** feature which has some hardcoded features like, exists, filename, lastedit etc. But I need to get the custom metadata of those files.

Please share some ideas.

Comment: could you please provide some example what custom metadata you want to get?

Answer (score 1):

@Sandeep

I am assuming you're looking to get the user-defined Metadata through Get Meta data Feature.

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible - the activity only returns the predefined set of Metada.

The list of Metadata supported has been documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity).

[image]

**Workaround**

One of the workarounds I can think is make use of the **Web Activity** in the ADF and hit the REST API [Get Blob Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties)

The Get blob properties API returns all user-defined metadata, standard HTTP properties, and system properties for the blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get the custom metadata of the files in question, but you need to jump through a few hoops.
In the example below, I have a custom metadata property called `maxmodifieddate` set on a specific file.
In your `Get Metadata` activity, go to the `Settings` tab and select `Add dynamic content`. Enter the value `userProperties`: [image]

This will return your userProperties array, but your values will be Base64 encoded:
[image]

You can use the `decodeBase64` function to retrieve your variable value, like so:

```
@decodeBase64(replace(activity('Get Metadata1').output.userProperties, 'MaxModifiedDate=', ''))
```

Which will finally output your metadata value (in this case saved to a variable called `myvar`):

[image]